# how can I insert a foreign key based on an auto-generated primary key

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I'm struggling to figure out how to relate two tables in Access (2003) and I'm looking for some guidance. I'm not an Access expert so it may be that I'm just using the right terminology in my search for an answer, so I apologize if this is a redundant question.

Anyway, I'm trying to build a database of activity (two or more tables) that occurs at my manufacturing facility. There is data I want to capture at the shift level and different data I want to capture at the hourly level within a specific shift and I want the two to relate.

The common denominator is the date and the shift rotation (either days or nights). Based on my understanding I need to develop a unique primary key for each "set" of data (i.e. the primary key for record #1 would be "5/8/14 Days", primary key for record #2 would be "5/8/14 Nights", etc) and use that primary key as a foreign key in the second table. I also know I can auto-generate a primary key (0,1,2,etc) via the autonumber feature for each set of shiftly data, but how to I get that into my hourly data without someone having to key it in? This is going to be used by my technicians and they're not going to have any clue that today's shift is number #93 or any other nonsensical, random number.

I've rambled long enough. Hopefully someone can point me to an answer. Please let me know if I haven't provided enough data.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I don't think the auto-number as a key field helps you at all - I would ignore that feature.  You're on the right track with a field for date_shift that is common to both tables.  Depending on what is easiest for the rest of your design, this could be a single field with both the date and the shift (as you described), or two separate fields - one for date and one for shift.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownListBox or ComboBox might be what you're looking for (use the ShiftHeader autoincrement key for the ShiftEvent unique/join key) and the ShiftDate+ShiftName as the display value. See [MS site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-list-box-combo-box-or-drop-down-list-box-HP005240581.aspx). I don't use MS Access often, but I use this technique often in other languages & databases

Answer (score 0):

I would say that rather than struggling around the shifts, think of something as below;

You have your normal data table with all the required fields and a special field for date and time for the data captured. 
You have another table which describes your shifts for day (Example: Morning Shift --> Start 08:00 AM --> Finish 11:59 AM, Afternoon shift --> Start 12:00 PM --> End 06:00 PM and so forth.

And then compare the data in the data table with the date time and the shift table with the times. I think this should resolve your question.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask questions if necessary..

Happy coding..!!